# How to use report result as input to Batch Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, batch, custom-button

Let's say I have a report with a specific result. Now i want to process this result in a batch process when the user triggers a order-button/link.

Is there a way to have a button on the report page which calls my batch process, using the report results as input?

Comment: You can't.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, This is not possible.

Your best bet is to recreate the report criteria in a SOQL query, which will be used in the `start()` method of your batch class.

As far as having a button click to call this batch apex method, you could have a custom button that directs to a VF page, the page then has an action method.  In your controllers action method, you can try to execute your batch process.

Comment: How can i add and place a custom button in the 'Run Report' Pane ? The user needs to know the result of the report bevor the user click the 'Order' button.

Comment: This is the part that cannot be done.  You would have to have a VF page to hold your custom button.  you cannot add a button to the Report page.